# foreach, амперсанд и рекурсия

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Надо заменить значения массива на другие, массив может быть любой вложенности. Можно сделать это по ссылке используя рекурсию?
Код просто как пример, цель которого изменить 'three' на 'five' используя рекурсию.

```
$a=['one'=>['two'=>'three']];    

function test($array)  
{  
    foreach ($array as $k=>&$v)  
    {  
        if(is_array($v))  
        {  
            test($v);  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            $v = 'five';  
        }  
    }  
    unset($v);  
}  
test($a);
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Только указание, что передаёте ссылкой должно быть в самой функции, а не у переменной. `function test(&$array)` иначе предупреждение в ранних версиях, критическая ошибка в более поздних.

Comment: мерси, то что нужно